# How to validate new install using Firebase Invites

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-invites

I done all the implementation of Firebase Invites in my android app through  [Firebase invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android#customize-the-invitation).

If new user(device) install my app through **Firebase Invite**, I will give some credits to that user.

Here:
 - How is validation done for user who has already installed the app?

- If the validation is not done from Firebase end then is there any way to do it??
- Do I have to generate my own reference code or will it be generated by firebase?

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

You will get appinvite id which is auto generated by the firebase and its upto you,how you use it.
You can save this id in the database such that it will saved in both profile 
,invited person profile and the person who invites such as you will access these ids easily inside the database.
Or put id as a key and put both person proile id inside it.

Hope this will help!!.

Comment: How do we know that firebase validates the install for the first time user? How should we implement it?

Comment: Do you using any signin method in your app? If you are using it then you must keep the unique id for each users even he/she uninstall it or logout or even deletes the account (if u provide functionality). Then check in your database that whether this unique id existed or not.If not existed then transfer the credits else not transfer it .